# Michael Hartl's Ruby on Rails Tutorial Chapter 2

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cloud9-ide

I'm working through [Michael Hartl's Ruby on Rails Tutorial](https://www.railstutorial.org/book/toy_app). When I try to initiate the command `rails _4.2.0_ new toy_app` in section 2.1, I receive the following error from the Cloud9 terminal:

> `Can't initialize a new Rails application within the directory of another, please change to a non-Rails directory first. Type 'rails' for help.`

I've tried refreshing the file tree to no avail.

Comment: You have already created one rails app, and are within that folder. Go back up one folder with `cd ..` and try `rails new toy_app` again. If you do a `ls -l` from the parent folder, you can see which rails app folder has already been created. A rails app folder will have `app`, `config`, `db`, etc. folders in it.

Comment: Just to add to Prakash's answer, you will need to delete that toy_app folder using "rm -r toy-app" before attenpting to re-create it.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.I should have prefaced that i'm new to programming ( dabbled with javascript) so please excuse the slow uptake. I've tried the following;

Answer (score 1):

If you're creating a new Rails Tutorial or Rails workspace, Cloud9 already sets up a new Rails project for you. That's probably the reason you're seeing this error. Since the rails project is already set up for you, you can go ahead and skip the `rails new <project>` step.

Alternatively, if you'd like to do make the Rails project yourself, you can select a 'Custom' workspace from the list of workspace types rather than 'Ruby on Rails' or 'Rails Tutorial'. Your workspace will then start with an empty project folder and you can run the above command without any problems.